# Who is wife of Vidura?

Tags: mahabharata, vidura

Vidura is an important character in Mahabharatam.

Is he married? If yes, who is his wife?

Answer (score 5):

VIDUR’S WIFE: SULABHA

In Mahabharata, Vidura is shown as an ideal devotee, a high class hermit, straight forward and a good statesman. Duryodhana was the only person sullen of Vidur’s straight forwardness. But Vidur had lot of affection for Dhritarashtra. So despite continuous humiliation by Duryodhana, he stayed at Hastinapur. Both Pandavas and Kauravas were equal for him. But the religious?hearted Pandavas were specially dear to him and he always wished well for the Pandavas. Vidur also had tremendous devotion for Lord Krishna.

Vidur’s wife was also a chaste woman of supreme order. She too had a high degree of devotion and abdication. When Lord Krishna visited Hastinapur as an emissary of Pandavas, he had not accepted Duryodhana’s request to stay in his palace but instead he chose to stay at Vidur’s home and accepted a simple meal there. When Lord Krishna reached Vidur’s home, Sulabha i.e. Vidur’s wife was taking her bath. So staying put at the door, Lord Krishna called out. Vidur was not at home then. Because of having a paucity of clothes, she was bathing completely naked. Suddenly she heard the Lord call out:”Open the door. I am Krishna here. I am hungry.” Hearing this call, Sulabha forgot her condition and like a mad woman ran and opened the door. God too understood her love ?

It is his promise also.

> PATRAM PUSHPAM PHALAMTOYAM YO ME
>
> BHAKTYA PRAYACHHATI |  TADAHAM
>
> NHAKTYUPADHTAMSHNAMI
>
> PRAYATATMANAH ||(Geeta: (/26)

Thus the Lord began to eat the banana skin relishing it. Both of them were sunk in affection- Sulabha in giving, while Lord Krishna sank in imbibing that love. They both were in a trance like condition. Meanwhile, Vidur too arrived. For sometime he stood amazed then seeing his wife behaving in an absurd way, he scoffed at her. Sulabha thus came around and began to feel sorry and ridiculed Krishna.

> CHHILAKA DINHE SYAMA KAHAN,
>
> BHULI TANA MANA- GYANA |
>
> KHAYE PAI KYON APNE,
>
> BHULI GAYE KYON BHAN ||

Lord Krishna laughed at that simple ridicule of Sulabha and said to Vidur:”Vidurji, you have come at the wrong moment. I was having extreme joy. I have always been pining for such food that is filled with love. Thereafter Vidur himself began to feed Lord Krishna with banana pulp. Lord Krishna however complained, you have fed me banana pulp with such a lot of affection but I could not find in them the relishing taste that I got in the peel. Tears of love than began to flow from Sulabha’s eyes.

Answer (score 4):

Vidhura's [mother was a Sudra](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01107.htm) woman.

> And Krishna-Dwaipayana, when he met his mother as before, informed her
> as to how he had been deceived by the seniormost of the princesses and
> how he had begotten a son upon a Sudra woman.

Bhisma married off the [daughter of King Devaka](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01115.htm) to Vidura.

> Meanwhile the son of the ocean-going Ganga heard that ***king Devaka had
> a daughter*** endued with youth and beauty and **begotten upon a Sudra
> wife.** Bringing her from her father's abode, Bhishma married her to
> Vidura of great wisdom. And Vidura **begot upon her many children** like
> unto himself in accomplishments.

Comment: Means that girl also born from kshetriya male and sudra female.

Answer (score 1):

Vidura's wife is Sulabha.It is mentioned that she was the daughter of King Devaka through a Shudra woman.Devaka was also father of Devaki and grandfather of Krishna.

Comment: You should cite some sources.