# What was the caste of Vidur's wife?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system, vidura

What was the caste of Vidur's wife? To which caste does Vidur's wife belong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The caste of Vidura's wife is Ugra, which needs to be treated as Sudra.**

Vidura is a sudra. You can observe it from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16449/661)

> "**Vidura said, 'I am born in the Sudra order** and, therefore, do not
> venture to say more than what I have already said. The understanding,
> however, of that Rishi leading a life of celibacy, is regarded by me
> to be infinite. He that is a Brahmana by birth, by discoursing on even
> the profoundest mysteries, never incureth the censure of the gods. It
> is for this alone that I do not discourse to thee, upon the subject.'
>
> [[Section 41, Sanat-sujata Parva, Udyoga Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05041.htm)

Vidura married a woman born to a Kshatriya father and a Sudra mother. You can observe it from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37803/661).

> "Meanwhile the son of the ocean-going Ganga heard that **king Devaka had
> a daughter endued with youth and beauty and begotten upon a Sudra
> wife**. Bringing her from her father's abode, Bhishma married her to
> Vidura of great wisdom. And Vidura begot upon her many children like
> unto himself in accomplishments.'"
>
> [[Section 114, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01115.htm)

So, the caste of the wife of Vidura is **Ugra**.

> **A Kshatriya may take three wives.** In two of them (viz., the one taken
> from his own order and the other that is taken from the order
> immediately below), he takes birth himself (so that those children are
> invested with the status of his own order). **His third wife being of
> the Sudra order is regarded as very inferior. The son that he begets
> upon her comes to be called as an Ugra.**
>
> [[Section 48, Anusasana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b013.htm)

Ugra caste needs to be treated as Sudras. You can observe if [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16890/661) and also [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201739.html)

> But people born of Vaisya women by Ksatriyas and Brahmanas **should be
> treated as Shudras, also men born of Shdra women**.
>
> [[71, Section 4: Social Customs and Institutions, Sukra Niti]](https://archive.org/details/Sukra_Niti/page/n169/mode/1up)

Thus, the wife of Vidura is of the Ugra caste and needs to be treated as Sudra.